# merge two images in android. One taken from a picture another from drawable resources. The position is not being proper.

Tags: android, merge

I have an Imageview suppose image1. Now There is an imageview called image2. image1>image2. I want to drag image2 onto image1 and save the new image using canvas. The images are merged but image2 is not being merged at the proper location. Any help would be appreciated.
This is my merging code

```
    int maxWidth = (bitmap1.getWidth() > resizedbitmap2.getWidth() ? bitmap1.getWidth() : resizedbitmap2.getWidth());
        int maxHeight = (bitmap1.getHeight() > resizedbitmap2.getHeight() ? bitmap1.getHeight() : resizedbitmap2.getHeight());
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(maxWidth, maxHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0f, 0f, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(resizedbitmap2, x, y, null);
```

This is how I drag the image2

```
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
   switch (arg1.getAction())
   {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

             //  attemptClaimDrag();

           moving=true;
           break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
           if(moving){
               x=arg1.getRawX()-ima2.getWidth()/2;
               y=arg1.getRawY()-ima2.getHeight()*3/2;
               ima2.setX(x);
               ima2.setY(y);
           }
           break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           moving=false;
           break;

   }

    return true;
}
```

Defined these two

```
    float x,y=0.0f
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First, overlap two images using `RelativeLayout`. Display it properly.

Second, convert this `RelativeLayout` into `Bitmap`.

**In layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image1"/>

    <!-- Change the position of the image. Now, its in center -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**In activity.java,**

```
// Set enable drawing cache first.
layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);


// Get Bitmap from RelativeLayout
Bitmap bitmap = layout.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: So, Do you mean I should keep the imageview of image1 inside a relative layout?

Comment: I don't want to hard code it like this. User will drag image2 on image1 anywhere he want to. But when the merged image is saved. I want it to be shown where it was dropped exactly.